# Resource for Learning Dynamic VF

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic, dynamic-vf-component

I am looking for a good place to learn dynamic VF. I did google it but did not find anything great. Does anyone know of a good resource where i can learn?
Thanks.

Comment: developer.force.com Is a very good site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is covered pretty well and gives some great coding examples in Chapter 13 of the Visualforce Developers guide.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf.

There are also some blog posts out there that can help give you use case and coding exmaples.  Here arte a few I came across.

http://learn4sfdc.blogspot.com/2012/08/examples-of-dynamic-visualforce.html

http://www.redpointsolutions.com/build-killer-visualforce-pages-with-dynamic-visualforce-components

http://www.tehnrd.com/dynamic-visualforce-components-why-they-scare-the-ish-out-of-me/

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :)